# Implementing login without user redirect and managing session with token

Tags: flutter, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am working with WSO2 and exploring different authentication methods, specifically focusing on session-based and token-based logins. With the session login, users are redirected to the WSO2 page for the login process, while token-based login involves creating a token without managing the user session.

I am looking for a solution that allows for login without redirecting the user, while still being able to manage the session. Additionally, I am interested in incorporating Single Sign-On (SSO) capabilities.

As I'm using Flutter for the front-end, I'm curious if there are any specific considerations or implementations for Flutter when working with WSO2 in this context. Has anyone successfully implemented such a solution with Flutter and WSO2? Any insights, code snippets, or relevant documentation would be immensely helpful.

Additional Context:

- WSO2 Identity Server version: 6.0.0
- Flutter version: 3.1